# Swift read large file into an array

Tags: swift

I'm trying to read a file into an array of strings in the Playground

```
let path = XCPlaygroundSharedDataDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("test.txt")

let data = try Data(contentsOf: path!)
let returnData = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)

var matrixData = returnData!.components(separatedBy: "\n").first!
let rows = Int ( matrixData.components(separatedBy: " ").first! )!
let columns = Int( matrixData.components(separatedBy: " ")[1] )!


let realData = returnData!.components(separatedBy: "\n").dropFirst().joined()
realData.count
let inputString = realData.components(separatedBy: " ")
```

The first two numbers in the input file indicate that it is a grid of A * B.

The "real data" indicates that the array has begun.

For a small input file (4 * 4) realdata.count reveals 16 (correct)

For a large input file (1000 * 1000) realdata.count is 999001 which is WRONG.

Why?

Is it to do with a limitation on array of Strings?

Comment: Can you please share your "test.txt" file's data ?, So people can easily solve problem.

Comment: 4 4
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 9 8 7 6 5 4 3

Comment: With \n after the second 4 - thus 4 4\n 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 9 8 7 6 5 4 3

Comment: You're doing lots of forced unwraps, I'm surprised you don't run into crashes :)

Comment: You're right of course, but I control the input so I guarantee it won't!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this to work I stripped the input string of \n first *as I don't use them* and then proceeded from there.

The only strange issue was an extra character at the end of the string, must have been a \n at the end of the input file.

```
let stripped = returnData!.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: " ")
var inputString = stripped.components(separatedBy: " ").dropFirst(2)
inputString = inputString.dropLast()
```

//inputString is now the correct length